# How can I enable Firefox for Android reader mode for my site?

Tags: firefox, fennec

I'm creating a site which will be responsive, and suitable for mobile devices. Earlier I discovered Firefox's reader mode, which was available for certain sites, and provided a clean view for reading. However, when I visit my site, I don't get the option to view in reader mode.

I'm curious how is it possible to enable it to my site, since it's a great feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reader mode in Firefox for Android is based on the readability.js code and the publisher guidelines for Readability should probably help:

https://www.readability.com/developers/guidelines

Comment: Thanks! I found it since, but it can be really useful if someone else searches for the same topic. I also forgot to take these in account when developing, so it's a good reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically this results from bad markup. Check your site with [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to see if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I checked my site, and it had only 1 error when I tested, namely an empty action for a form. I don't think that can cause the issue, and I corrected it, tested, but still no go. I'm pretty sure there's some pattern I have to follow, since it would be really hard to program an intelligence, that can decide from any markup, what it should show.